# Angular Bootsrap Multi Select Add Remove Componenet Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

can anyone please tell me whether there is any plugin in angular, bootstrap for add remove modal component like as shown below in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a ready-to-intstall module with bootstrap styling, but the basic implementation is quite simple:
http://jsfiddle.net/andytjoslin/aeSaJ/3/

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="fling">
    <select multiple="true" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item for item in selectedItems">
    </select>
    _________________
    <select  multiple="true" ng-model="available" ng-options="item for item in availableItems">
    </select>
        <br />
    <button ng-click="moveItem(selected[0], selectedItems, availableItems)">
        Move sel --&gt;
    </button>
    <button ng-click="moveItem(available[0], availableItems, selectedItems)"> 
        &lt;-- Move sel
    </button>
        <br />
    <button ng-click="moveAll(selectedItems, availableItems)">
        Move all --&gt; 
    </button>
    <button ng-click="moveAll(availableItems, selectedItems)">
         &lt;-- Move all
    </button>
    {{selectedItems}}
    {{availableItems}}

    </div>
</div>


function fling($scope) {

    $scope.moveItem = function(item, from, to) {
        var idx=from.indexOf(item);
        if (idx != -1) {
            from.splice(idx, 1);
            to.push(item);      
        }
    };
    $scope.moveAll = function(from, to) {
        angular.forEach(from, function(item) {
            to.push(item);
        });
        from.length = 0;
    };

    $scope.selectedItems = ['a','b','c'];
    $scope.availableItems = [1,2,3];
}
```

it should be easy to add bootstrap classes here.

Comment: how about up and down functions

Comment: Also if i select two items , only one item is passing

Comment: well, that's your starting point - start exploring if there is no ready meal

Comment: i've already gone through this code at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/cyw1j3iarNc/tyzpk_6zRPcJ ....

Answer (score 4):

You can use Angularjs based **[ngListSelect](http://nidhishkrishnan.github.io/ngListSelect/)** plugin for achieving this

**[Working Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/Ert7SV/preview)**

simply import

minified

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nidhishkrishnan/ngListSelect/master/ngListSelect.min.js"></script>
```

non-minified

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nidhishkrishnan/ngListSelect/master/ngListSelect.js"></script>
```

Add `ngListSelect` as a dependency to your app

```
angular.module('your-app', ['ngListSelect']);
```

and use the `ngListSelect` directive in your template like as shown below

```
<ng-list-select selected-list="selectedList" key="name" available-list="availableList" button-style="olive" panel-style="olive"></ng-list-select>
```

[image]

Comment: is there any custom directive for that..??

Comment: @vishal u can use this directive

Comment: thank you so much, Is  ngListSelect  maintained by you? if this is so, then thanks a lot Nidhish, you really helped me and the other developers (y)