# angularjs error passing JS object array to JSON

Tags: angularjs

I followed this [SO-link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30025390/7620991) and tried to use it. If i pass the same array as in the answer i get the result. Now i tried to replace the array with my input like below, but i am getting [object object]. i tried to convert js object to json but i am getting errors. the directive is not allowing it. how to get the desired result.

In controller

```
App.controller('PartsController',['$scope', 'Parts', function($scope,Parts) {
            $scope.parts = {};

            $scope.availablePartsTemp = [];
            $scope.availableParts = [];

            $scope.fetchAllParts = function() {
                $scope.availablePartsTemp = Parts.resource.query(function(
                        response) {
                    angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
                        if (item) {
                            $scope.availableParts .push(item);
                            }
                    });
                });
            };

            $scope.selectedList = [];

        } ]);
```

In html

```
    <ng-list-select selected-list="selectedList" 
                           key="part" available-list="availableParts" ></ng-list-select>
<br/>
      <b>availableList::</b>{{availableParts | json}}
      <br />
      <b>selectedList::</b>{{selectedList| json}}
```

Comment: What does the response object look like?

Comment: It just shows [object object]. actually it has 2 columns, id and part. it prints the json of my array as shown in the example from that answer. its just not showing on the list boxes

Comment: So you are calling $scope.fetchAllParts() from a button click or something like that?  Also, $scope.availableParts .push(item) should be $scope.availableParts.push(item)

Comment: Yes exactly. That is copy paste mistake here.

Comment: So response is an array of objects, something like [{id:1, part:'Hose'},{id:2, part:'Clamp'},...]?

Comment: YES it is right. actually it shows in <b> tag

Comment: Hard to know for sure without seeing all related code but it could very well be that digest cycle has completed before the promise is fulfilled.  In other words, your array is updated after the DOM is finished updating.  If that's the case you can add  $scope.$apply(); after your forEach to force a digest cycle

Comment: Can you take team viewer Please?

Comment: No, I'm sorry I can't.

Comment: Okay Thank you for the input. i tried to apply, but getting dbg is undefined error.

Comment: @user7620991 share here i will help

Answer (score 0):

Not getting exactly what the issue you are facing, I have created a similar mockup similar to yours, and its seems working fine.

Please take a look

**[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uu2gMWQNz115e7JyQoCS?p=preview)**

**script**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngListSelect'])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {

  //////////// Mocking Parts //////////////
  Parts = function(){};
  Parts.resource = function(){};
  Parts.resource.query = function(){
    deferred = $q.defer();
    var responseJson = [{id:1, part:'Hose'},{id:2, part:'Clamp'}, {id:3, part:'Pipe'}, {id:4, part:'Screw'}, {id:5, part:'Hammer'}]
    deferred.resolve(responseJson);
    return deferred.promise;
  }; 
  //////////// Mocking Finished ///////////


  $scope.parts = {};
  $scope.availablePartsTemp = [];
  $scope.availableParts = [];
  $scope.fetchAllParts = function() 
  {
    $scope.availablePartsTemp = [];
    Parts.resource.query().then(function(response) {
      angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
        if(item) 
        {
          $scope.availableParts.push(item);
        }
      });
    },
    function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }); 
  };
  $scope.selectedList = [];
  $scope.fetchAllParts();
});
```

**html**

```
  <body ng-app="app"> 
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <br/>     
      <ng-list-select selected-list="selectedList" key="part" available-list="availableParts"></ng-list-select>
      <br/>
      <b>availableList::</b>{{availableParts | json}}
      <br />
      <b>selectedList::</b>{{selectedList| json}} 
     </div> 
  </body>
```